# Low rank factorization of structured matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Let $n_1, n_2, n_x$ and $n_y$ be positive integers, and denote $[n]:=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Consider
\begin{equation}
u_{ij}(x,y) = \langle f_i(x), g_j(y)\rangle
\end{equation}
for some $f_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n_y}$, $g_j\in\mathbb{R}^{n_y}$ and for all $(i,j)\in[n_1]\times[n_2]$ and $(x,y)\in[n_x]\times[n_y]$. (The inner product is the standard one in $\mathbb{R}^{n_y}$.)

We may note that for fixed $(x,y)$ (say $(1,1)$), the matrix $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1\times n_2}$ whose entries are the $u_{ij}(1,1)$ is of rank at most $n_y$:
\begin{equation}
U = \begin{bmatrix}
\langle f_1, g_1\rangle & \ldots & \langle f_1, g_{n_2}\rangle\\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
\langle f_{n_1}, g_1\rangle & \ldots & \langle f_{n_1}, g_{n_2}\rangle
\end{bmatrix}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n_y} \begin{bmatrix}
f_1^{[k]}g_1^{[k]} & \ldots & f_1^{[k]}g_{n_2}^{[k]}\\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
f_{n_1}^{[k]}g_1^{[k]} & \ldots & f_{n_1}^{[k]}g_{n_2}^{[k]}
\end{bmatrix} 
= \sum_{k=1}^{n_y} f^{[k]}g^{[k]^\top},
\end{equation}
so a sum of $n_y$ rank-1 matrices, with $f^{[k]}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1}$ and $g^{[k]}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_2}$.

My question is:

> Can one assemble a matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1n_xn_y\times n_2}$ or $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1n_x\times n_2n_y}$ from $u_{ij}(x,y)$ which is of rank at most $n_xn_y$ (or similar)?